# centos gdrive script, upload to new folder

Tags: shell-script, centos, google-drive

I'm using https://github.com/prasmussen/gdrive

Hello,

I'm trying to run a daily script that creates a folder in Google Drive and then uploads a bunch of tar archives in it. So far I can create the folder but can't upload if I don't have the id of the folder and I have no idea how to get it. For the time being, I'm uploading to a default folder and manually moving the files.

This is what I have so far

```
#!/bin/bash

drive folder -t $(date '+%d-%m-%y') //makes the folder

for file in /home/backup/*.tar
do
drive upload -f "$file" -p (the newly created folder id)
done
```

Answer (score 1):

According to your linked-to page, when you create a directory gdrive prints the id of it. Look at the example it gives:

```
$ gdrive mkdir gdrive-bin
Directory 0B3X9GlR6EmbnY1RLVTk5VUtOVkk created
```

So you can use, for example, awk to keep just the 2nd word and then provide this to the later upload commands:

```
#!/bin/bash
dir=$(drive mkdir $(date '+%d-%m-%y') | awk '$3=="created"{print $2}')
: ${dir?}
for file in /home/backup/*.tar
do   drive upload -p "$dir" "$file"
done
```

The `: ${dir?}` stops the script if we fail to find an id.

Comment: Thanks for the example, helped me to capture the word i needed. It's the first time I need a bash script. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

you need to find the id of the folder where you want to upload the files I suggest you create the pas, for example type

```
$ gdrive ./gdrive list
1yJz6M094WNWVPoM09u2m8GjoLiumSdxl   Empresa                           0.0 B      2018-06-29 12:12:03   
1TS8b3JDx6RNeIvFN6HqAI9gNuNrs5D-b   Banco de Dados                    0.0 B      2018-06-29 12:11:42   
**1RYvaOGgf6E4HikDZ0cKKwoG-aShe6j6E**   Sistema                           0.0 B      2018-06-28 14:53:28
```

copy the id of the folder where you que and paste after -p
ex.:

```
#!/bin/bash
dir = $ (drive mkdir $ (date '+% d-% m-% y') | awk '$ 3 == "created" {print $ 2}')
: $ {dir}
for file in /home/backup/*.tar
of the drive upload -p "$ dir" "$ file" **1yJz6M094WNWVPoM09u2m8GjoLiumSdxl**
done
```

Comment: I don't think your code is working. Can you revise it to make it executable?